# Some Kind of memory error in C program

Tags: c, memory, crash, malloc

I use this struct.

```
typedef struct {
char *title;
char *description;
int idNumber;
char* tvProducer;
DateTime startTime, endTime;
EventType subjects;
} EmmissionType;



void Emmission_read(FILE* f, EmmissionType* Emmission) {
EmmissionType * temp;
temp=Emmission;
temp->title = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
...
```

Here program crashes and the debugger give back the message.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault
Next line doesn't matter. I changed the next command and nothing happend

Edit:

The first argument is an open file pointer for reading and the second is a pointer to the variable who get the data

```
void Top_read(FILE* f, TVNodeType head) {
TVNodeType ptr;
ptr = head;
int ekp, i;
fscanf(f, "<%d>\n", &ekp);

//Edw 3erw poses ekpompes exw kai 8a ftia3w ena struct gia tin ka8e mia
// system("pause");
Emmission_read(f, ptr->anEmmission);
ptr->next = NULL;

for (i = 1; i < ekp; i++) {
    ptr->next = mallocwarp(sizeof(TVNodeType*));

    ptr = ptr->next;

    // system("pause");
    printf("Hello\n");
    Emmission_read(f, ptr->anEmmission);
    ptr->next = NULL;
    // system("pause");
}
printf(" Top read\n");

}
```

Now main only reads the data

```
int main() {

FILE *f = NULL;
f = fopen("input.txt", "r");

TVNodeType listaPtr = NULL;
listaPtr = (TVNodeType) mallocwarp(sizeof(struct TVNodeStruct));
Top_read(f, listaPtr);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you call the function? What do you pass for the `Emmission` argument? Please *edit your question* to include that information and code.

Comment: Do you, anywhere, allocate memory for the `anEmmission` pointer?

Comment: can you explain this.

Comment: What does `mallocwarp()` excatly do? Anything more then the standard `malloc()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listaPtr->anEmmission` is pointer, which seems to not have been initialised to point to any valid memory.

So de-referencing its value here

```
temp->title = ...
```

to access `title` provokes undefined behaviour.